# Get data from form params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new for rails and ruby. I try to make a simple project and have this problem. I have a view with some text fields on it, when I press submit button, in my controller I need the values from this fields as strings, I try this way `params[:field1]`, but the value is in this format {"field1"=>"some_value"}, it's not a string and I have the problems with it. How can I solve it?

UP: 
view code

```
<%= form_tag :action=>:login_user do %>
    <div class="field">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <%= text_field "field1", "field1" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <h2>Password</h2>
        <%= password_field "field2", "field2" %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
    </div>

    <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post your form code? It seems you are having some problem in your form structure.

Comment: Can you paste your view code....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag "field1" %>
<%= password_field_tag "field2" %>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
params[:field1]
```

is correct way.

Your params is a hash:

```
params => {"field1"=>"some_value"}
```

so to get `field1` you should call `params[:field1]`

**UPD**

For your structure (that is actaully bad) you should call for params this way:

```
params[:field1][:field1]
params[:field2][:field2]
```

better to use `text_field_tag` and `password_field_tag` in your case:

```
<%= text_field_tag :field1 %>
<%= password_field_tag :field2 %>
```

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/password_field_tag

Comment: I think problem is in the structure of form. For normal form, one can use tag helper.

Answer (score 1):

Using the code you have pasted you will have to access it as `params[:field1][:field1]` and `params[:field2][:field2]`. So as Ashish suggested you should use text_field_tag. Or in the conventional way of Rails, use `form_for` to bind both the fields to a single key and use `update_attributes` or `create`.